# Proving that a sequence of partial sums is convergent

Tags: real-analysis

I've been revising for my real analysis exam and one of the questions I came across was

"Let $(d_k)$ be a given sequence such that $d_k \in $ {0,1,...,9} and define $a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n {d_k10^{-k}}$. Prove that the sequence $a_n$ converges."

The model solution provided involves proving the sequence is Cauchy and hence convergent. However, could you not do something similar to this:

$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n {d_k10^{-k}} ≤   9\sum_{k=0}^n {10^{-k}} ≤ 9\sum_{k=0}^\infty {10^{-k}} = 9\cdot {1 \over 1- {1 \over 10}} = 10 $

So $(a_n)$ is an increasing sequence bounded above by 10, hence it converges by the Axiom of Completeness of $\mathbb R$

Is that correct or am I making an error?

Comment: Where have you shown that $(a_n)$ is increasing?

Comment: That is correct. Actually the [convergence of a monotone sequence of real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_sequence_of_real_numbers) - wich relies on the least upperbound property of $\mathbb R$ - is enough.

Comment: Is there anything that says $d_k$ cannot only be $0$?

Comment: Nope, I posted all the information the question gave

Comment: The sequence is not necessarily monotone e.g. consider $a_1$ with none of the $d_k = 0$ and $a_2$ with all $d_k = 0$ etc.

Comment: @Daniel $$a_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} d_k 10^{-k}=d_{n+1}10^{-(n+1)}+\sum_{k=0}^n d_k 10^{-k} = d_{n+1}10^{-(n+1)}+a_n\geq a_n$$
so $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is non-decreasing.

Comment: Indeed, you are proving that sequences of the form "$\mbox{some.}d_1d_2d_3...$" always define a real number.